# Подключение прокси в SmtpClient

Tags: c#, proxy, smtp

Каким образом можно подключить прокси (http\s  | socks4\5). Имеется вот такой метод:

```
static void Send(string login, string password , string mailSend, string subject , string body , string proxyHost, int proxyPort)
{

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 587);
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(login, password);

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress(login);
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailSend));
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Возможно ли это вообще? Пробовал некоторые решения взятые на SO, но не помогли.

Comment: Стоит указать язык программирования. А вообще посмотрите документацию на класс SmtpClient, скорее всего поддержка прокси должна быть встроена в него, что бы это работало

Comment: Извиняюсь, добавил к заголовку темы яп)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844835/sending-mail-through-http-proxy а тут смотрели

Comment: Да, смотрел, но там написано что в настройках интернет соединения уже прописаны прокси, а мне бы желательно сделать коннект\отправку письма через прокси без изменения параметров сети, возможно есть какие-то другие способы отправки письма , где есть возможность установки проксей?

Comment: А тут глянь https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/smtpserver_socksproxyuser.htm

Comment: То , что выше скинул Roman leromenko , в данном способе используется сторонняя коммерческая длл, есть ли какие-либо способы юзинга проксей без финансовых затрат?)

Comment: Всё ещё актуально , возможно кто-то мог бы поделится решением проблемы...

Comment: @GetResult Вас устроит моя собственная библиотека (с открытым кодом на гитхабе)? Она, конечно, не умеет многого, но через прокси отсылает почту используя mail.ru.

Comment: @Zergatul да, не мог бы ты оставить ссылку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Репозиторий: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib
проект Zergatul

Пример отправки почты:

```
var smtp = new SmtpConnection();
smtp.Proxy = new HttpProxy("ip-адрес", 8080);
smtp.Connect("smtp.mail.ru", 587);

smtp.ExtendedHello("mail.ru");
smtp.StartTls("mail.ru");

smtp.ExtendedHello("mail.ru");
smtp.AuthPlain("mail_acc", "password");

smtp.Mail("mail_acc@mail.ru");
smtp.Recipient("recipient@gmail.com");
smtp.Data(EmailFormatter.GetText("Bill Gates <mail_acc@mail.ru>", "Subject", "Steve Jobs <recipient@gmail.com>", "Hello"));
//smtp.Data(EmailFormatter.GetHtml("Bill Gates <mail_acc@mail.ru>", "Subject", "Steve Jobs <recipient@gmail.com>", "<h1>Hello!</h1><a href='stackoverflow.com'>click!</a>"));

smtp.Quit();
```

Есть возможность отправлять текстовые и html-сообщения. SMTP-протокол и прокси классы очень простые, вы можете "переместить" мои классы к себе в проект.

`HttpsProxy` класс не был проверен на реальном прокси, я или что-то не понимаю, как он работает, или не смог найти реального https-прокси.