# Python smtplib через https прокси

Tags: python-3.x, http, email, https, proxy

При помощи модуля socks могу отправить письмо через socks4/5 сервер:

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, 'ip', port)
socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.mail.ru:465")
s.login("log", "pass")
```

Как отправить почту через http/s прокси?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Краткий ответ - никак.

Чуть-чуть шире.

Socks работает на 4-м уровне модели OSI и передает трафик как есть.
HTTP-прокси работает на 7-м уровне и отвечает только за HTTP протокол.
SMTP протокол также относится к 7-му уровню и, соответственно, имеет свой набор софта и библиотек для работы.

Единственный вариант, который я вижу - использовать API  (как у тогоже [гугла](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/))

Comment: Вы неправы, через HTTP прокси можно пересылать бинарные данные, а значит можно использовать его для любого протокола, который работает поверх TCP.

Comment: @Zergatul бесспорно я могу быть неправ. Но давайте ближе к телу. У вас есть стандартная smtp библиотека «стандартного» языка (python, java, php, C#, etc). Как с помощью этой библиотеки пообщаться через обычный http прокси с удаленным smtp сервером? Можете привести пример кода? Я этим вопросом интересовался давно. Решения не видел. Натолкнете на мысль или покажите решение - скажу вам огромное спасибо! :]

Comment: Это зависит от того, как устроена библиотека, и поддерживает ли она расширение в плане переопределения сокета. Обычно такого нет. Я писал свой класс для работы с smtp, который поддерживает соединение через прокси, в том числе и http: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771073/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-smtpclient/794680#794680

Comment: @Zergatul о, спасибо! Поиграюсь с ней.